# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \frac a n$ converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence

> Examine for convergence the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \frac a n$.

The series is divergent if we consider $a_n = \sin \frac a n$, $b_n =\frac{ a}{n}$ then apply the comparison test.

But this series is not a series with positive terms.

According to the question, it is an alternating series.

How can we deal with it as an alternating series?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: It is not alternating.

Comment: Why is it not alternating?

Comment: Alternating means every positive term is **always** followed by a negative term and vice versa.

Comment: So which type of series is this and how to test it's convergence ?

Comment: If $a>0$, your series $S$ has only positive terms; convergence can be concluded from what you wrote. If $a<0$, look at $-S$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: *(... eventually ...)*

Comment: This answers (a generalization of) your question: [Uniform convergence of $\sum n^\alpha \sin{\frac{x}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3995893/uniform-convergence-of-sum-n-alpha-sin-fracxn)

Comment: @metamorphy oopsie!